# Payment gateway not sending request parameters to URL?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, payment-gateway

this is my following code for custom payment gateway.
when i am trying to place order at check out page it shows connecting to server exception that was created by me. when we check parameters in firebug, it only shows checkout and response is failure.
I am try to send request parameters to gateway URL but not getting success.
Please tell me where i was done the mistake?
Thanks In Advance..

```
    public function process_payment( $order_id ) {
    global $woocommerce;

    // Get this Order's information so that we know
    // who to charge and how much
    $customer_order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    // Are we testing right now or is it a real transaction
    $environment = ( $this->environment == "yes" ) ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';

    // Decide which URL to post to
    $environment_url = ( "FALSE" == $environment ) 
                       ? 'https://www.qpayindia.com/wwws/Payment/PaymentDetails.aspx'
                       : 'https://www.qpayindia.com/wwws/Payment/PaymentDetails.aspx';

    $QPayID = $this->QPayID.'`'.$this->order_total;

    // This is where the fun stuff begins
    $payload = array(
        // Authorize.net Credentials and API Info
        "QPayID"            => $this->QPayID.'`'.$this->order_total,
        "QPayPWD"               => $this->QPayPWD,
        "CaseNumber"                => $this->CaseNumber,

        "Currency"                  => $this->Currency,
        "TransactionType"               => $this->TransactionType,
        "ResponseURL"               => $this->ResponseURL,

        "Mode"                  => $environment,
        "Amount"                => $customer_order->order_total,
        "OrderID"               => $customer_order->get_order

    );

    // Send this payload to Authorize.net for processing
    $response = wp_remote_post( $environment_url, array(
        'method'    => 'POST',
        'body'      => http_build_query( $payload ),
        'timeout'   => 90,
        'sslverify' => false,
    ) );

    if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) 
        throw new Exception( __( 'We are currently experiencing problems trying to connect to this payment gateway. Sorry for the inconvenience.', 'spyr-authorizenet-aim' ) );
    else
    {
        throw new Exception( __( 'Connecting to server.', 'spyr-authorizenet-aim' ) ); 
    }
    if ( empty( $response['body'] ) )
        throw new Exception( __( 'Authorize.net\'s Response was empty.', 'spyr-authorizenet-aim' ) );


    // Retrieve the body's resopnse if no errors found
    $response_body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );

    // Parse the response into something we can read
    foreach ( preg_split( "/\r?\n/", $response_body ) as $line ) {
        $resp = explode( "|", $line );
    }

    // Get the values we need
    $r['ResponseCode']             = $resp[0];
    $r['Message']         = $resp[1];
    //$r['response_reason_code']      = $resp[2];
    //$r['Message']      = $resp[3];

    // Test the code to know if the transaction went through or not.
    // 1 or 4 means the transaction was a success
    if ( ( $r['ResponseCode'] == 100 )  ) {
        // Payment has been successful
        $customer_order->add_order_note( __( 'Authorize.net payment completed.', 'spyr-authorizenet-aim' ) );

        // Mark order as Paid
        $customer_order->payment_complete();

        // Empty the cart (Very important step)
        $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();

        // Redirect to thank you page
        return array(
            'result'   => 'success',
            'redirect' => $this->get_return_url( $customer_order ),
        );
    } else {
        // Transaction was not succesful
        // Add notice to the cart
        wc_add_notice( $r['Message'], 'error' );
        // Add note to the order for your reference
        $customer_order->add_order_note( 'Error: '. $r['Message'] );
    }

}

// Validate fields
public function validate_fields() {
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've confused the logic here:

```
if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) 
    throw new Exception(....);
else
{
    throw new Exception(....); 
}
```

So you throw an Exception regardless of the reponse, and this way you never reach the code further down. An Exception always breaks the current flow, and unless caught with "try...catch", it breaks out of the program. For a quick test, try this (mind the curly brackets by the way):

```
if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
    throw new Exception( __( 'We are currently experiencing problems trying to connect to this payment gateway. Sorry for the inconvenience.', 'spyr-authorizenet-aim' ) );
} else if ( empty( $response['body'] ) ) {
    throw new Exception( __( 'Authorize.net\'s Response was empty.', 'spyr-authorizenet-aim' ) );
} 

// Retrieve the body's resopnse if no errors found
// ...
```

Comment: Thank you let me try this one.